# Silverlight 4 - Configure Self-Hosted WCF Service to use SSL

Tags: silverlight, wcf, ssl

I have a Silverlight 4 application that uses WCF services on the same server (self-hosted).  Everything works fine, but now I want to convert my WCF services to use SSL.  I am using CustomBindings and can't quite find the combination to get this done.  I am using relative URLs on the client side, and hope this is not causing a problem.  Here are the important bits of my Web.config file:

```
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"  />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="6553600"/>
          <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="00:10:00"/>
        </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>

    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="MyApp.Web.Services.ProjectService.customBinding0"
          receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <binaryMessageEncoding />
          <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="MyApp.Web.Services.ProjectService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyApp.Web.Services.ProjectService.customBinding0"
          contract="MyApp.Web.Services.ProjectService" />
      </service>
```

My ClientConfig looks like this:

```
    <configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="CustomBinding_ProjectService">
                    <binaryMessageEncoding />
                    <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
                </binding>
           </customBinding>
       </bindings>
       <client>
            <endpoint address="../Services/ProjectService.svc" binding="customBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_ProjectService" contract="SearchProxy.ProjectService"
                name="CustomBinding_ProjectService" />
     </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I just don't understand how the bindings work in both the server and client.  I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: You say that the service is "self-hosted", but you posted a web.config; is the service hosted in IIS, or do you have a program with a ServiceHost instance which you actually open?

Comment: What I meant was that my WCF services are hosted within the Web project of my Silverlight project.  I just want to convert them to SSL, but I also need to be able to debug/develop on my local machine.  I'll take a look at your answer and see what I can find.  Thanks!

Comment: When I set the httpsTransport in my service (and set the httpsGetEnabled=true in the behavior) , then try to update it from my silverlight app, I get the following error: "There was an error downloading metadata from the address. Please verify that you have entered a valid address". Any ideas?

Comment: You changed the service address (from http to https), so you'll need to "configure service reference" to update the address in the client.

Comment: The error I mentioned is what I get when I try to add a NEW service reference. Once I make the above changes in my web.config, I am no longer able to access the service at all through Visual Studio.

Comment: What happens when you browse to the .svc address? Do you see the WCF help page, or is there an error here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

If you want to use SSL on localhost you'll need to be using IIS Express 7.5 (or full IIS if you're on a server doing dev - unlikely).

You'll need a clientaccesspolicy.xml file stored in the root of the Web application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <access-policy>
       <cross-domain-access>
           <policy>
               <allow-from http-request-headers= "SOAPAction">
                   <domain uri="https://*"/>
               </allow-from>
               <grant-to>
                    <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
               </grant-to>
           </policy>
       </cross-domain-access>
     </access-policy>
```

Example server-side Web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="SecureBasicHttpBinding">
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="SomeBehavior" >
        <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
          <defaultPorts>
            <add scheme="https" port="443" />
          </defaultPorts>
        </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>

  <serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <serviceActivations>
      <add relativeAddress="SomeService.svc" service="MySilverlight.Web.SomeService"/>
    </serviceActivations>
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>

  <services>
    <service name="MySilverlight.Web.SomeService"
             behaviorConfiguration="SomeBehavior">

      <endpoint address="SomeService"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="SecureBasicHttpBinding"
                bindingNamespace="https://MySilverlight.Web.SomeService"
                contract="MySilverlight.Web.ISomeService">
      </endpoint>

      <endpoint address="mex"
                binding="mexHttpsBinding"
                contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Example client-side:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
      <system.serviceModel>
          <bindings>
              <basicHttpBinding>
                  <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISomeService" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                       maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                      <security mode="Transport" />
                  </binding>
              </basicHttpBinding>
          </bindings>
          <client>
              <endpoint address="https://localhost/SomeService.svc/SomeService"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISomeService"
            contract="MySilverlight.Web.SomeServiceReference.ISomeService"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_ISomeService" />
         </client>
    <extensions />
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

IIS 7.5 will setup your localhost certificate automatically.

Comment: Once I installed IIS Express, things started to work.  I did not know that the built in web server in VS did not support https.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you update the service reference on the client project? That should update the clientconfig file with the correct binding. One thing I am noticing right now is that you're using <httpTransport> on the client binding and <httpsTransport> on the service. Try changing the client to use <httpsTransport> as well.

Also, if your SL app is downloaded from an HTTP:// address, then a call to a service in HTTPS is considered to be a cross-domain call, so you'll need a cross-domain policy file as well.

Comment: Trying to update or reconfigure the service once the web.config changes are made gives the error I described above in my other comments.  I still have not found a solution to this.

Comment: Can you try browsing to the .svc file to see if it shows you any activation errors?